# How to create a PHP file that returns a list of nodes as XML?

Tags: nodes, 6

How do I create a PHP file that returns a list of nodes as XML when called if I have a menu structure like this:

```
<GalleryXML>
--gallery 1
---Item 1
---Item 2
---Item 3
```

And I want a url like `localhost/getgallery.php`

this url will then return my gallery as xml, something like this

```
<galleryXML>
    <gallery name="gallery1">
        <item name="item1">
            <image>localhost/site/default/image1</image>
            <imagethumb>localhost/site/default/image1</imagethumb>
            <url>http://google.com</url>
            <description>lorum ipsom</description>
        </item>
    </gallery>
</galleryXML>
```

Where `Image`, `Imagethumb`, `url` and `description` are fields on the item node

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is less an answer and more a pointer to old d6 projects that might help with your search. :) http://drupal.org/project/node_export | 
http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus | http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what i did:

1. I created a view.
2. Changed the style to XML data document (Need to download the [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module)
3. Added the fields I needed and [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue)
4. Added a filter to filter by node type so it looks like this:

[image: Views settings]
then I added a new page with a path:

[image: Page settings]

my end result looks like this:

```
 <node>
    <node>
        <Description>blablalbla</Description>
        <Image>
        sites/default/files/articles/siteadmin/test.png
        </Image>
        <ImageBig>sites/default/files/test.png</ImageBig>
        <Link>derp</Link>
        <gallery>Gallery1 For flash</gallery>
    </node>
    <node>
        <Description>sdfsdfdf</Description>
        <Image>
        sites/default/files/articles/siteadmin/test.png
        </Image>
        <ImageBig>sites/default/files/test.png</ImageBig>
        <Link>sdfdf</Link>
        <gallery>Gallery2 For flash</gallery>
    </node>
</node>
```