# Returns a list of nodes as XML?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, navigation

I'm trying to do [something like this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12686/how-to-create-a-php-file-that-returns-a-list-of-nodes-as-xml) with Drupal 7.

I need to generate either an XML file or a number of xml files based on the sub-parts of the over-all "Navigation" menu.

[image]

I have multiple "Portals", each with a list of pages... I need to generate an XML file for each portal, and be able to customize the hell out of it.

I've been trying Views... with XML Sitemap, feeds, etc... I just can't seem to get anything workable.

Answer (score 2):

Will Views RSS do what you want?  It typically throws articles/nodes out as RSS(XML),  and you can modify it to produced more structured output if you wish.

Comment: I'll check that out today.